# Negotiate last day of work

Tags: resignation

My last day would be on July 27 due to 1 month notice plus holidays. However, I understand that the team is on holiday and won't return until August 1. I then propose to do handover on August 1. Still the management team asked to extend to August 2.

As a good gesture, I don't want the management team to get a feeling that I'm not mindful to stay for another day, but I don't feel comfortable to come anymore. One of the reason is I'm not sure about my mother's health condition as she will need surgery. Could you please advise? Thank you.

Comment: You go there till the August 1 since you "agreed" to it, but if you dont want the second day then dont. Easy as pie. They cant blame you for their failure. You are supposed to Handover everything in the 1 month notice. Thats what it is basicly for, besides finding a replacement that is.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you asking if you should stay for the additional day or if you can get out of it?

Comment: OP's last day would be 27nd of July. OP proposed the 1st of August. They ask the 2nd of August. what is there to clarify @JasonJ?

Answer (score 5):

If your last day is the 27th, then your last day is the 27th. Period. If they want something from you, *they* need to make sure this happens before that date. If they are away, that's *their* problem.

Anything you do on top of this is up to you. If you want to do it, fine. If you don't, fine. Just make sure you stick to your word. If you agree to do something, do it. If you decline it, then don't do it.

As you did not mention why you left that job, there is little we can help you with. You can decide to still help them for free. Or for money. Or not at all. It's up to you.

Comment: @keshlam I interpreted the OP as *this team* being on holiday, with other teams or departments still working. That would not be his problem. If the whole shop is closed, then you are absolutely right.

Comment: +1 OP could also trade a day or two of holiday for pay (I understand this is common in the US). That could solve the off-by-one neatly.

Answer (score 2):

Check the terms of the notice period. If it's really one calendar month, their holiday break isn't your problem. But it's often a specific number of *working* days, in which case company holidays are *not* counted.

If they want to add a day, they're presumably going to pay you for that additional day, right? That may not be an awful thing, depending on where you're going from here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you work in an "employment at will" state or country, or are you under contract?

If you are employed at will, then you set the terms and date of your last date. The flip side is a company can terminate you at any point. Do what you need to do to take care of yourself and your family. Staying a few extra days at a job you are leaving isn't worth anyone's health.

Answer (score -3):

"A few more days?" Oh sure, "we're just talking about 'the following Tuesday.'"  *Why not?*

*"Of **course** they'll pay you!"*

Therefore: "when the time comes to leave, always be sure that you leave a **happy** customer!"

**But(!)** **Also(!!)** *"Yes, obviously, 'Mom comes first!'"* Believe me, you are **surrounded** by people who have wrestled with that same sad problem.

Therefore: *"talk to(!!)* the 'powers that be!'" Explain your situation. Look for "common ground." And, kindly remember that every person who you  might be talking to is ... "a *person,* too."

They're obviously *very satisfied* with your work, given that they're asking you to help them out ... of course, "for pay" ... basically "over the weekend." And, *yeah,* they completely understand ... "they have, or *had,* mothers, too." **:-(** So, "just *talk it out."* Maybe you can accommodate them; maybe you can't. But ... *talk.*

Comment: `"Of course they'll pay you!"` I would't be too sure. OP had better communicate that directly, or at the very least make it absolutely clear he considers coming in later a favor. He may also not want to reveal his mother's condition, but oh well.